# Mongodb findOneAndUpdate replaces other values on PATCH

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on an API, in my frontend, I send a PATCH request to a route that can update weight, height or gender. The structure of my schema model is this:

```
/** @format */
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    userNumber: { type: Number, required: true },
    description: { type: String },
    verified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isSubscriber: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isDisabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    characteristics: {
      height: { type: Number, default: 0 },
      weight: { type: Number, default: 0 },
      gender: { type: String, default: 'other' },
    },
    acceptedTerms: { type: Number, required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Now my controller actions are quite similar to find update those 3 values:

```
exports.changeSex = async (req, res, next) => {
  // Requirements
  const userId = req.params.userId;
  const newGender = req.body.gender;

  console.log('userId: ' + userId);
  console.log('newGender: ' + req.body.gender);

  try {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: userId },
      { characteristics: { gender: newGender } }
    );
    console.log('User successfully updated.');
    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, gender: newGender });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', err);
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err });
  }
};
```

The problem I'm facing is each time I execute one of these 3 actions, one replaces the others.

For example, changing gender, will output height: 0, and weight: 0, and if I update weight: 10, gender returns to gender: 'other'.

It seems findAndUpdateOne replaces everything using the default values of my schema, which would be a pity to rewrite the entire thing, I tried updateOne and I find the same result. I also tried this:

```
...
try {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: userId },
      { $set: { characteristics: { gender: newGender } } }
    );
...
```

and also:

```
try {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: userId },
      { characteristics: {$set { gender: newGender } } }
    );
```

And both examples also repeat the same pattern.

Answer (score 2):

This not a correct way to update `object` value.

Try this:

```
   exports.changeSex = async (req, res, next) => {
  // Requirements
  const userId = req.params.userId;
  const newGender = req.body.gender;

  console.log('userId: ' + userId);
  console.log('newGender: ' + req.body.gender);

  try {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: userId },
      { $set: {
           "characteristics.gender": newGender
        }
      },
      { returnDocument: 'after' }
    );
    console.log('User successfully updated.',user);
    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, gender: newGender });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', err);
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err });
  }
};
```

1. `{ returnDocument: 'after' }` is options of query. it's return document
   after updating.

If you have any doubt watch example : https://mongoplayground.net/p/w5WlqHxHghU